# Visual Studio installer project does not overwrite output .EXE file

Tags: .net, installation, exe

I've created a visual studio installer project to copy an applications' output to a folder on the target PC. Now, when I want to distribute a newer version, i create an installer with an increased version. Properties 'RemovePreviousVersions' and 'DetectNewerInstalledVersion' are set True.

What happens is: all files in the target folder are overwritten by the installer, except for the .EXE file, which is not replaced.

Did I forget a setting somewhere?

Thanks,

Comment: No, checked that already myself :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a lot of trying and setting properties on and off, it appears that if you want an assembly or executable to be overwriten by the installer, you have to increase the version of that project each time you build an installer (and not only the version of the installer project!!!). If you don't do this, the original file is kept.

Select the executable/assembly project > Properties > application > Assembly Information. Here you can modify the version.